# File from client to S3 through PHP

Tags: php, stream, amazon-s3

I need service that allow to upload large files to S3, only for authenticated client.
So, 
1. I need to check if is client has an access (for example HMAC or any unique key) 
2. Check file format (extension/MIME-type, it must be only MUSIC)
3. If everything is ok - upload it to S3

Looks very simple. But, I don't want to store file at the service. I want to stream it directly to S3 after all checkings. Or, if auth. data is invalid, request must be aborted and file wouldn't e send.

Can you advise what technology I should use or right way for searching?